# Give an example of a vector space which has 125 elements

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Give an example of a vector space which has 125 elements.
I don't know how proceed!!!
Is there any technique about the field??

Comment: Before posting, have look here at this site, e.g., [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/101835/number-of-elements-on-a-finite-vector-space).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just consider the field $\mathbb Z_5$ and mutiply it $3$ times with itself. Then new set over the field $\mathbb Z_5$ is a vector space with $125$ elements.

Answer (score 1):

$\frac{\mathbb{Z}_5[x]}{(x^3)}$ as a $\mathbb{Z}_5$-module, which is $\{a+bx+cx^2\mid a,b,c\in\mathbb{Z}_5\}$.

This is the same as $$V=\left < [a,b,c]\mid a,b,c\in\mathbb{Z}_5\right>$$

which have $5^3=125$ elements.